# In excel or R; how to represent the density of 1 or blank (i.e. SNP present or absent) along the length of the chromosome?

Tags: r, excel

I have a column with physical position along the chromosome from 0.1 - 25,526,585, and along this chromosome I have a 1 if there is a SNP and a blank if not. I would like to make a line graph or something to show any peaks of SNPs .I can't manually count SNPs per say every 1000th position,because the chromosome is >25m in length and the positions are at irregular intervals. Does anyone have a bright idea for how to do this, I would be very grateful. 
Data layout:

```
Phys_Position   Mutant_SNP
 0.0    
 0.1    
 0.1    
 0.1    
 0.1               1
 0.1    
 0.1               1
 0.1    
 0.1    
 0.2    
 0.2    
 0.2               1
 0.2               1
 0.2    
 0.2    
 0.3    
 0.3    
 0.7    
 0.7    
 0.7    
 0.7    
 0.7    
 0.7    
 1.4    
 1.5    
 1.6    
 1.7    
 1.7               1
 1.8    
 1.8    
 1.9    
 1.9    
 2.0    
 5.4
 ...
 25,526,585
```

dput output:

```
structure(list(PHYS_POS. = c(37, 55, 89, 102, 105, 107, 116, 
117, 121, 166), Phys_Position = c(" 0.0 ", " 0.1 ", " 0.1 ", 
" 0.1 ", " 0.1 ", " 0.1 ", " 0.1 ", " 0.1 ", " 0.1 ", " 0.2 "
), Mutant_SNP = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA), X = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X.1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X.2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), X.3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    X.4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X.5 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X.6 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("PHYS_POS.", "Phys_Position", 
"Mutant_SNP", "X", "X.1", "X.2", "X.3", "X.4", "X.5", "X.6"), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

@nyc new data:

```
first.bp    mutations
1       0
1000001 0
2000001 0
3000001 0
4000001 0
5000001 0
6000001 0
7000001 0
8000001 0
9000001 0
10000001    0
11000001    0
```

Comment: Thanks MarcelG for the formatting.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to make a graph which is 0 at 0.0, 2 at 0.1, 2 at 0.2, 0 at 0.3 and so on?

Comment: That is correct, exactly. But it doesn't need to be at such small intervals, as that would be too much data...up to 25 million. It could be in groups of say 1-1000 or 1-10,000 thus reducing the data points considerably. I can't figure out how to make such counts per sub-section??

Comment: I think I should do something as: `subsetData <- subset(df, Phys_Position >= 0 & Phys_Position < 10,000)` and then take the sum of the second column. Can't make and test something for you atm, a code is running. Assuming that the data is stored in `df`.

Comment: Thanks very much MarcelG I will give it a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will return a vector `allSNP` which contains for each interval the number of SNP. You can adjust the `step` to any value you want and you should `df` to your data and you're good to go. The last thing for you to do is to make a graph of the results.

```
#Create Data
Phys_Position <- c(0, 5, 10005, 20001)
Mutant_SNP <- c(1, 1, 0, 1)
df <- data.frame(Phys_Position, Mutant_SNP)
df$Phys_Position <- as.numeric(df$Phys_Position) #<-------- added after edit  

#find first and last value
start <- df$Phys_Position[1]
limit <- df$Phys_Position[nrow(df)]

#intiliaze values
step <- 10000
end <- start + step
allSNP <- NULL
while (start < limit)
{
  subsetData <- subset(df, Phys_Position >= start & Phys_Position < end)
  nrSNP <- sum(subsetData$Mutant_SNP, na.rm = TRUE)
  allSNP <- rbind(allSNP, nrSNP)

  start <- end
  end <- start + step
}
```

Comment: MarcelG. Error in start + step : non-numeric argument to binary operator? I have uploaded my csv as stringsasfactors=false, and up until this point it has read the data correctly i.e. the start and end points. What do you think is the problem? Thanks again.

Comment: I have added the output above. My first column is the physical position (called PHYS_POS) but I am using the 2nd column Phys_Position (which has more manageable numbers i.e. the first col divided by 1000).

Comment: @nya sharp thinking, I forgot due to my own example data

Comment: @MarcelG. R is running the script, it's taking a long time. Maybe my step size was too small.

Comment: @nya. Thanks for all your help, it worked in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, we can use `sapply`.

```
step.size <- 100
pos <- sapply(seq(1, tail(dat$PHYS_POS., 1), step.size), 
    FUN=function(x) sum(dat$Mutant_SNP[dat$PHYS_POS. >= x & dat$PHYS_POS.< (x + step.size - 1)], 
        na.rm = TRUE))

pos
[1] 0 2
```

As per @MarcelG's comment, here is an explanation for the code.

The `sapply` function uses a sequence from 1 to the last value in the PHYS_POS. column offset by a step size. (For the calculation, division in the Phys_Position column loses precision and is not necessary, although it is certainly easier to read for a human.) The function then feeds the sequence values one at a time to the function defined in `FUN=` as a variable `x`. We use the variable `x` to subset, which values in the column Mutant_SNP to sum. `na.rm = TRUE` specifies that missing values are ignored.

The result can be converted to a `data.frame` and plotted.

```
res <- data.frame(first.bp = seq(1, tail(dat$PHYS_POS., 1), step.size),
    mutations = pos)
plot(1, xlim = c(0, max(pos)), ylim = c(0, nrow(res)), type = "n")
apply(res, 1, FUN=function(x) segments(0, x[1]/step.size, x[2]))
```

Comment: Agreed, way more efficient. But less clear what is going on for inexperienced R users (my feeling is that OP is one)

Comment: The problem deals with genomic data and those are large.

Comment: Thanks nya for the code and description (I am rubbish at R). I will give it a go.

Comment: @nya. Sorry as usual I get it wrong...getting this error: Error in seq.default(1, tail(R_SNP$PHYS_POS., 1), step.size) : 'to' must be of length 1?? Any help appreciated.

Comment: @nya. NB: Error  applies to sapply script. Should I be adding something where you have an "x"?

Comment: @Cathyt10 What error? `x` should be fine. `dat` should be the name of your data.frame.

Comment: @nya "Error in seq.default(1, tail(R_SNP$PHYS_POS., 1), step.size) : 'to' must be of length 1". Yes .dat I am putting my dataframe name. I think the error relates to NAs in the SNP column?

Comment: @nya. I have removed NA and still get the error message.

Comment: @Cathyt10 `tail(R_SNP$PHYS_POS., 1)` is not a single number. You can replace it with a known length of your chromosome. Or with `max(R_SNP$PHYS_POS., na.rm=T)`, providing your positions are ordered.

Comment: @nya. So I type: tail(R_SNP$PHYS_POS., 1-25526585931)? Sorry it's not clear and I am still getting the error, also get an error with max(R_SNP$PHYS_POS., na.rm=T). Thanks, sorry.

Comment: @Cathyt10 The syntax is: `seq(from=1, to=25526585931, by=step.size)` If you type the tail command in R, what value does it return?

Comment: @nya. Think that syntax has worked it's now processing............Thanks.

Comment: @nya. All the steps worked and I have some data output, however for each section it is saying 0 mutations? Must be something to do with the data format of my Mutant_SNP column. It looks OK, but type is showing as unknown. I think we are nearly there please don't give up! Thanks.

Comment: @nya. Ps I wasn't sure what this was for and I didn't use it; pos
[1] 0 2.

Comment: @nya. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Cathyt10 Glad to help. Your Mutation_SNP column was probably not numeric. Use `R_SNP <- apply(R_SNP, 2, FUN=function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))` to change all columns.